# What is this jazz scale?

Tags: theory, scales, jazz

I was jamming on a music piece and found that this scale fits the harmony.

I have found the scale by using my ear, 
I see it is very similar to diminished F scale but can't find what scale it is.
Here are the keys : **F Gb Ab A B C D Eb** <<< EDITIED

The song is on Am.
Melody line : E E F D | D D E C | C C D B

Harmony_________________ :  Dm chord| Am chord| here Gb as only a tone.

from the Gb voice or tone I have derived the scale mentioned above.

I think it is a jazzy scale.
Do you know a scale like this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The song has an E in it, whereas your notes include an Eb.Should the 'song be IN Am, rather than ON Am? - Just trying to clear up red herrings!

Comment: sorry for misconceptions.
Yes I meant "in Am"  aha so my scale does not fit maybe only  its first notes fit.
So from where did the Gb tone come ?
Is it a leading tone ?
(It sounds nice)

Comment: Is the next bar Gmaj? If so, the Gb is an F# leading tone/note.

Comment: it goes back to Am. maybe I have to post the melody line exactly to clarify for you.
but thank you for your info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be called an F Diminished scale. In classical music theory it would usually be called an Octatonic Scale. It is a mode of limited transposition (it has a constantly repeating tone-semitone interval pattern). It has a number of interesting properties, for instance, the scale contains a pair of diminished 7th arpeggios, a semitone apart.

For any particular starting pitch, there are two possible Octatonic scales: one starting with a tone; one starting with a semitone. Interestingly, there are only three possible Octatonic scales (if you consider them by pitch set, and ignore the starting note). For instance, the scales starting: E-F; F-Gb; F#-G. All other Octatonic scales will contain EXACTLY the same notes as one of these scales (hence "limited transposition").

As this scale has 8 notes, two of the pitch names always have to have the same letter (Ab and A in your example). This is also sometimes reflected in chord types associated with this scale; for instance the Gb, Ab and A in this chord would make it a b9/#9 chord, even though, in theory, it has two thirds.

Comment: - just like the diminished chords - there's only really 3 of those, with several names each.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Bob Broadley's comprehensive answer. For better understanding here's a visual image of this scale. The symmetry is apparent:

[image: Octatonic scale]

In the context of Am key (based on the C diatonic scale). The dominant would be E7. It it a good place for alterations. In that case a different mode of this octatonic scale could work well, a half-tone lower, based on E. This way the E octatonic would contain the E7 chord (E Ab B D), as well as its alterations: b9 (F), #9 (A), b5 (Bb) and 13 (Db) in addition.

The other thing is that both F and E octatonic contain the Ab diminished chord which work well with the Am chord. In fact these two added together make up the A harmonic minor scale. It is used widely - eg. from Bach to Latin jazz.

Comment: Bearing in mind there are two often used octotonic scales, the halftone/tone, and the tone/halftone, it's confusing to talk about 'F and E octotonic', as they could well be the same set of notes!  If they are not, then both together will contain every note known to Man ! Assuming you mean the E half/whole, that would contain E,F,G,G#,A#,B,C#and D. Not a harmonic minor. If you meant F,F#,G#,A,B,C,D,Eb that's not either. Can you help me to understand ?

Comment: First thank you for your information. I meant F,F#,G#,A,B,C,D,Eb so it is not ? I'm trying to figure out why they used F# key in the harmony.

Comment: Ah, sorry if the answer was not clear. I meant the canonic octatonic scale, ie. the one with the lowest entropy. In this case it is the half/whole. In general we can think about 3 different modes of this scale. One making the 110... pattern (half/whole), 101 (whole/half) and 011... pattern (without a common name). This one on the image can be called F half/whole  (or equally Gb whole/half, etc.) and the one I was talking about that could be also suitable can be called E half/whole.

As for the reference to the A harmonic minor: Am chord + Ab dim chord together make up the A harmonic minor.

Answer (score 3):

It is in fact a half/whole diminished.
It goes up the scale insteps that alternate between a semitone and a tone. The oppo. to this, is, unsurprisingly, the whole/half diminished scale. No prizes for working out the configuration !